# How to deploy Rails app on Heroku with Active Resource Api call to data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, heroku, activeresource

my Ruby on rails application  not support Active record  rails app used active resource  API for featch data from another server , how i deploy the rails application to Heroku with no migration , schema , database file app,

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that without any migrations although heroku will assign you a default database which you will never use. It will not create any problem IMO. Go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: there is also not present the schema file in rails application ,so how now Heroku my database schema , and  i call outside API in MOdel to fatch data, that API desing by JAva devloper